# Dependency of arguments

Tags: arguments

I would like to have a secondary environment named `\defin` that uses a parent environment, the latter taking three arguments.  `\defin` will call `\statement` with a hard-wired first argument, the rest of the arguments behaving as the parent.

Would this implementation be what I have to do, doing a simple test for `#2` in `\defin` ?

Would like that `\defin` is exactly like `\statement` except that the first argument in set to `Definition`.

The problem is that `\begin{defin}{This}[That]` does not put `That` within `()` to get `Definition This (That)`.  But gives me `Definition This That`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{statement}{mmo}
  {
    \IfNoValueTF {#3}
      { \noindent #1 \ #2 \, }
      { \noindent #1 \ #2 \ (#3) }
  }
  { \vspace{0.3cm} }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{defin}{mo}
  { 
    \IfNoValueTF {#2}
      { \statement {Definition} {#1} }
      { \statement {Definition} {#1} {#2} }  
  {}

  \begin{defin}{This}
    Some Text
  \end{defin}    

  \begin{defin}{This}[That]
    Some Text
  \end{defin}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us in a short compilable TeX code how you want to use your environments? Then we have not to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: What's the reason for not using the theorem-like environments already provided by LaTeX? Anyway, you're missing the `\endstatement` instructions.

Comment: I want to learn to do my own things using simple examples like these.

Comment: Is `statement` supposed to be a command, to be called by `\statement{one}{two}{optthree}`, or an environment created by `\NewDocumentEnvironment`?  Should the third argument to `statement` be optional as with `{mmo}`, or mandatory as with `{Definition}{#1}{#2}`?

Comment: `statement` is an environment.  `defin` should also be an environment.  Basically defining an environment by calling a more general environment with the first argument prefilled.

Comment: Perhaps what I am trying to do is not possible. I now realise that I am calling statement as a command.  What's one to do?

Comment: The third argument to `statement` is optional.  `defin` is supposed to pass the second and third arguments of `statement`, the first one being `Definition`.

Comment: Given the examples it appears that you are changing your account name constantly which makes refering to earlier questions (even questions on the same day) problematic as it's not clear if you are the same person or not.

Comment: Note that (with good reason) latex never uses `\noindent` to suppress indentation in this way, you should (as previously explained to someone who may be you) this should be a theorem environment or a one item list.

Comment: why have you declared an _environment_ `statement`  which you then use as a command? If you want the command form why didn't you use `\NewDocumentCommand` ? As it is the code is unbalanced you call the start of statement but never the end.

Comment: Are you referring to the use of `{%`.  Indentation is not the biggest problem.  Can one call the functionalities of an environment from another environment definition ?

Comment: No I am refering to `\noindent` even if you get the form used to not give errors it is not going to produce a good definition as it lacks all the features needed for a heading definition such as not allowing a page break after the heading.  Yes you can use one environment in the definition of another but you are not doing that.

Comment: impossible to say given the sketch you have shown, why do you want two definitions at all? As shown possibly you just want to declare `\statement` as a command, but perhaps you have some reason to have it as an environment. But also it's pointless having a conversation if all previous comments have to be ignored as the account has changed.

Comment: Would like to see an example of using an environment in the definition of another.

Comment: statement is an environment I might use because of its generality.  I can define any promise I want rather than being limited to `Definition`, etc as the first word..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `o` for an optional argument, the argument always has to go in square (rather than curly) brackets.

Because `statement` is an environment, you also need to use

```
\begin{statement}

\end{statement}
```

You were also missing a closing brace, I think, in the definition of `defin`.

I'm not sure which horizontal spaces are intended and which may be spurious, so you may not want comment signs everywhere I've put them, but you probably want to be more careful with line endings and spaces if you want to avoid the introduction of mysterious spaces in the output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{statement}{mmo}
{%
  \IfNoValueTF {#3}
  {\noindent #1 \ #2 \,}
  {\noindent #1 \ #2 \ (#3)}%
}
{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{defin}{mo}
{%
  \IfNoValueTF {#2}
  {%
    \begin{statement}{Definition}{#1}%
  }{%
    \begin{statement}{Definition}{#1}[#2]%
    }%
  }{%
  \end{statement}%
}
    
\begin{defin}{This}
  Some Text
\end{defin}    

\begin{defin}{This}[That]
  Some Text
\end{defin}

\end{document}
```

[image: defin with and without an optional argument]

Comment: I never realised what the `%` was all about in `{%` and `}%`.  Thought they were just comment lines with nothing.

Comment: @Barytoc You don't need them if you're using `expl3` but, yes, otherwise unwanted spaces are a problem. And they can be a real pain to track down in code. The `%` is a comment, so you're turning what would otherwise be a space into a commented space. (Newline is a space.)

Comment: What would I need to do ? Call `ExplSyntaxOn` ?  Does the manual describe them somewhere.  The syntax is extremely weird.

Comment: And at times you have two as '%%'.  Tolkien invented this ?

Comment: @Barytoc Sorry. Just noticed that. It's a typo I've now corrected. Tolkien would have come up with something more interesting. `\ExplSyntaxOn` means spaces and newlines are ignored. But you'd then have to explicitly add any spaces you *do* want.

Comment: What does one have to do to use `expl3` so that one would not need the `%`.

Comment: @Barytoc If you do `\ExplSyntaxOn`, you don't need `%` for spaces until you say `\ExplSyntaxOff` and then you need to worry about spaces again. But it means you have to specify any spaces you do want explicitly e.g. `\ExplSyntaxOn Some ~ text ~ here.\ExplSyntaxOff Now spaces count again.`. Without the `~`, you'd get `Sometexthere.Now spaces count again.` But you don't need to comment line endings etc.